# PHP-Pinterest Api - get total pins and repins for a domain/webpage

Tags: php, api, pinterest

Is it possible to **get total pins and repins count** for a **webpage/domain** through any possible ways using Pinterest Api?

**Tried this way -->**

https://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?&url=http://Hjnorthbay.com

**It returns zero count.**

But there were pins exists for Hjnorthbay.com if we check through this way,

https://www.pinterest.com/source/hjnorthbay.com/

And also what about **pinterest domain api**, is it depreceated?.

Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

It works not for whole domain, just for special page. There is no way to get total pins for whole domain.

I just tried for few pages of my site, you should also use `http://` and name domain same as your link looks like.

For example

> FAIL!
>
> receiveCount({"url":"http://www.ticlotel.com/layered-medium-curly-hairstyles-2017.html","count":0})
>
> PROFIT!
>
> receiveCount({"url":"http://ticlotel.com/layered-medium-curly-hairstyles-2017.html","count":107})
>
> FAIL!
>
> receiveCount({"error":"Invalid
>   Url","url":"Ticlotel.com/layered-medium-curly-hairstyles-2017.html"})